# image.setImageDrawable crashes app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, imageview

Can't figure out why, but I have no errors on eclipse, (simple classroom app - button creates new activity, sending in a textView and an imageView to the new activity) but as soon as I run my app and I press my button, the app crashes and I recieve this error on the LogCat

Logcat

```
02-12 17:13:26.297: E/AndroidRuntime(398): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-12 17:13:26.297: E/AndroidRuntime(398):  at edu.colum.iam.SecondPage.onCreate(SecondPage.java:38)
```

When I take that line out (and any other line that would affect it) the app runs fine, and it sends my textView over. Here is the .java I have, and I'll post the xml just incase as well.

IntentsActivity.java

```
public class IntentsActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button btn = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(myListener);

}




// Create an anonymous implementation of OnClickListener
View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() 
{ 

    public void onClick(View v) {


Intent myIntent = new Intent(IntentsActivity.this, SecondPage.class);
        String text = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).getText().toString();
        ImageView Selection = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1));
        myIntent.putExtra("Text", text);
        myIntent.putExtra("img", R.drawable.icon);
or an image)
        startActivity(myIntent);
//endclass
```

SecondPage.java

```
public class SecondPage extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);

    //get extras
    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    String text = b.getString("Text");

    //show text
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tv.setText(text);

    //show image
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    int resource = getIntent().getIntExtra("img", R.drawable.icon);
    image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(resource));
    // ^ this is the line my logcat crashes as an error
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/hello"
/>
<Button android:text="@string/Button1" android:id="@+id/button1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:text="@string/FirstLayout"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/icon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

second.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/textView1"   
android:text="@string/SecondLayout"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>

<Button android:text="@string/Button2" android:id="@+id/button1"          
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `imageView1` is in main layout instead of second layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `layout` you posted, `imageView1` is in your first xml not in `second.xml` which is the one you inflate in `SecondPage.java` so naturally it is `null` when you try to call a method on it.

You will need to add the `ImageView` to your `second.xml`.

Comment: I'm new to Java, so I don't want to mess anything up, do I just copy and paste the ImageView to the second.xml?

Comment: That should be fine. I don't see any properties that would screw it up. You will just need to place it wherever you need it. You can't access `View`s in other `layout`s than the one that's been `inflated` such as by calling `setContentView()` or using a `LayoutInflater` and adding it to the current `layout. But, since you are new, I wouldn't worry about that second part yet.

Comment: We just learned about inflators yesterday actually! thanks man this works, I actually took out the "android:src="@drawable/icon" " line on the second.xml (to make sure it's not recreating it on the secondpage.java and taking it from the image on the intentsactivty.java) and it works! thanks again man.

Comment: I would recommend having different `id`s for all of your `View`s. Its not necessary if they are in different files but it may get confusing. If you do, just make sure to change the `id` you reference in your Java code, also. I'm glad its working now.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the same ImageViews in different layout files (I don't know why you would name them the same) and then access them from within your code as long as you have set the right layout inside onCreate or wherever you want to access those components. So, yes, just copy the ImageView to the second.xml and it should work.